# Submit Form with AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

When I press the `submit` button, the site will refresh. But I have written `a AJAX code,` so the site shouldn't refresh, yet it does.

But i can't find the mistake. I have the same functionality on other pages too, and there I don't have any Problem. So there it works, but I can't find a mistake in this code :

```
$("#uploadlinkhoverForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "uploadHover.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    var string = document.getElementById('userFileLinkHover1Image').value;
                    var letztePos;
                    var laengeString = string.length;

                    letztePos = string.lastIndexOf('\\');
                    var extString = string.slice(letztePos+1,laengeString);

                    var string2 = document.getElementById('userFileLinkHoverImage').value;
                    var letztePos2;
                    var laengeString2 = string2.length;

                    letztePos2 = string2.lastIndexOf('\\');
                    var extString2 = string2.slice(letztePos2+1,laengeString2);

                /*$("#targetLayerHover").html(data);
                $("#targetLayerHover2").html(data);*/

                //Bild einfügen
                //insertLinkHoverImage(extString,extString2,document.getElementById('userLinkHoverImage').value);

                },
                error: function() 
                {

                }           
           });
        }));

<div id = "imagehoverbar">
        <form id="uploadlinkhoverForm" action = "index.php?sendHover=1" method="post" >
            <table border=0 width=900px>
                <tr valign = top>
                    <td width=10px><img src = './images/blank.png' height=25px width=10px border=0></td>
                    <td width=425px>
                        <table border=0 height=1px width=700px>
                            <tr valign = middle>                            
                                <td width=370px><span class = "text_schriftart_bezeichnung"><span id="targetLayerHover">No Image</span>&nbsp;<input name="userHoverImage1" id = 'userFileLinkHover1Image' type="file"></span>&nbsp;</td>    
                                <td width=370px><span class = "text_schriftart_bezeichnung">Hover: <span id="targetLayerHover2"></span>&nbsp;<input name="userHoverImage" id = 'userFileLinkHoverImage' type="file"></span>&nbsp;</td>                          
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width=370px><span class = "text_schriftart_bezeichnung"><span id="targetLayer">Verlinkung</span>&nbsp;<input name="userImageLink" id = 'userLinkHoverImage' type="text"></span>&nbsp;
                                <span class = "text_schriftart_bezeichnung"><input type="submit" id ='submitlinkimage2' value="Upload" class="btnSubmit upload_button" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td align = right><img src="./images/toolbar/pfeiloben_kl.png"  style="width:25px; height:25px;" alt="" onMouseDown = "ausblendenToolbar('imagehoverbar');"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Why did my page refresh?

Comment: Check for JS errors.

Comment: there are no Errors, i found one mistake. now my Problem is, the form doesn't send data to Ajax.

Comment: Are you sure you're binding the event handler properly?

Answer (score -1):

what you're actually doing is directing the form to /index.php?sendHover=1  . because that is what you've instructed in the  tag

```
<form id="uploadlinkhoverForm" action = "index.php?sendHover=1" method="post" >
```

why not modify your  to this:

```
    <form id="uploadlinkhoverForm" onsubmit= "return sendform(this);">
```

edit your JS from:

```
$("#uploadlinkhoverForm").on('submit',(function(e) { 
  //ajax stuff....
}
```

to

```
function sendform(form){
  //ajax stuff...
}
```

Comment: so i but the other one works. so i have to delete the "Action"?

Comment: I have no idea, but now it works i don't know why thx. i'm sry to waste your time